# Android intent - how to open my own app from choosing list and get the message I entered

Tags: android, android-intent, implicit

I'm really new to android and I have this problem:
I'm writing an application where you can enter a text and click the send button to pass the text to other SMS applications so the person sends the text.
I know I should use ACTION_SEND, what I don't know is how can I get the message I wrote to be opened in my own application so I can send it with my own app. ( after selecting my own application from choosing list) 
I will be really glad if you explain it to me,
also if there should be any changes in manifest and activity file.
thank you.

Comment: You should follow the documentation, if your app receiver is yours https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html, or if not you should try to find what kind of intent the app receiver is listening for.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

            if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                    final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    }
                    if (messages.length > -1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                    }
                }
            }
       }
}
```